# Failed to spawn: unexpectedly timed out while waiting for signal from process with PID

Tags: android, frida

```
frida -U -l shen.js -f com.11111

Frida 16.1.3 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit 
Commands:    /_/ |_|       
help      -> Displays the help system    . . . .       
object?   -> Display information about 'object'    . . . .       
exit/quit -> Exit    
More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/  
Connected to ONEPLUS A6010 (id=e4a32c46) Failed to spawn: unexpectedly timed out while waiting for signal from process with PID 11349
```

Failed to spawn: unexpectedly timed out while waiting for signal from process with PID 11349

Mobile enabled ro.debuggable == 1

Answer (score 0):

This is what i do for samsung A50 and worked

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw '/'
chmod 777 /
adb shell "su -c setenforce 0"
setprop persist.device_config.runtime_native.usap_pool_enabled false
settings put system screen_off_timeout 100000000
exit
exit
```

now you can run frida-server
terminal 1 (use cmd for windows)

```
adb shell "su -c /data/local/tmp/frida-serverarm64"
```

terminal 2 (maybe powershell for windows)

```
frida -U -f package.app -l script.js
```

Good Luck